# Git remote branches are wrongly listed twice

Tags: git, github, git-remote

If I do a `git branch -a`, I get my local branches listed correctly, but my remote branches are listed double... e.g.

```
master  
remotes/github/master  
remotes/origin/master
```

I think the reason for this is that I started out with a remote called github mapped to my github repository URL and then later changed its name to origin, still keeping the same URL.

If I do a `git remote -v`, I get the correct single name/url listing:

```
origin  git@github.com:username/Repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/Repo.git (push)
```

I tried removing the remote URL completely in the config file so that `git remote` would return nothing, but `git branch -a` still returned those doubled remote branches.

How do I get rid of this double listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
git branch -d -r remotes/github/master
```

Comment: I get: error: `remote branch 'remotes/github/master'`   not found.